# What does x = x do anything special in TypeScript/Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, font-awesome

In the documentation for Fontawesome/Angular it shows an example of how to add an explicit reference (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome#installation):

> **Explicit reference** Not as convenient as using the library but if you believe "explicit is better than implicit" then this method is for
>   you.
>
> src/app/app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

> src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  faCoffee = faCoffee;
}
```

What does faCoffee=faCoffee mean in TypeScript/Angular? Is this a bug, a hack or does it perform some magic?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the template `app.component.html` of the component cannot access the imports used in the typescript file `app.component.ts`.

The template file can only access the members from the AppComponent class. And this is why you have to declare a member if you want to use an import in a template file.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a variable class `faCoffe` to your component class **because you use it on the template**. You also could rename this variable to any other name you want.

The import reference will not do nothing, it only makes the variable `faCoffe` of the dependecy available to use in the file.

This code will work to:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faCoffee as freeIcons } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  faCoffee = freeIcons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular templates only have access to the public properties of the component they're attached to.

So if your component has a function called `myFunction()`, your template can call it with something like `(click)="myFunction()"`.

The same is true for variables. In your case you have a property that's imported into the component, but this would only be available to the template if the component makes it a property. Personally I prefer to prefix with a `public` as I think it makes the strategy easier to read:

`public faCoffee = faCoffee;`